# Is Charles Certificate expired?

Tags: ios, ssl, charles-proxy

I just downloaded the latest Charles 4.6.5 and used it on my simulator, try to download the Charles certificate and noticed it expired at 25 Sep 2023.

[image]

I tried downloading from https://chls.ssl/pro, also shown as expired.
Used `openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in charles-proxy-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem` to check it

Is there no newer certificate available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the updated certificate, go to

Charles -> Help -> SSL Proxying -> Reset Charles Root Certificate

[image]

Remove the existing iOS Certificate Profile

Setting -> General -> VPN & Device Mgmt -> The Cert, and remove it,

Then reinstall it using https://chls.pro/ssl

A detail guide from https://charlesdocsy.com/2021/12/29/expired-charles-proxy-root-certificate/

After that, restart your Charles and Simulator if it is still not working.